# Rails - *_path returning absolute path instead of relative path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working through chapter 5 of https://www.railstutorial.org. When running my rails server the footer link is rendering:     "href=localhost:3000/about" instead of "/about".

Here is the relevant code for the view:

```
<%= link_to "About", about_path %>
<%= link_to "Contact", contact_path %>
```

Here is my routes.rb:

```
root           'static_pages#home'
get 'help'  => 'static_pages#help'
get 'about' => 'static_pages#about'
get 'contact' => 'static_pages#contact'
```

I included the contact link because it is returning the desired "/contact". Which is driving me a little crazy.

I'll include my test file as well:

```
test "layout links" do
  get root_path
  assert_template 'static_pages/home'
  assert_select "a[href=?]", root_path, count: 2
  assert_select "a[href=?]", help_path
  assert_select "a[href=?]", about_path
  assert_select "a[href=?]", contact_path
end
```

The resulting error is:

```
SiteLayoutTest#test_layout_links [/sample_app/test/integration/site_layout_test.rb:9]:
Expected at least 1 element matching "a[href="/about"]", found 0..
```

Comment: Are you sure the full page is in the source of the page ? sometime it's just the browser that displays the absolute url.

Comment: @Baldrick the browser is displaying the absolute URL for the about but not the contact link. I'm not sure how the tests work.

Comment: Check if the problem persists after you named the routes:  `get 'about' => 'static_pages#about', as: 'about'`  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#naming-routes

Comment: @Baldrick thanks, I'll try that when I get home and report back

Comment: @Baldrick I tried what you suggested but it is still rendering in the browser as "http://localhost:3000/about". Do yo have any other ideas?

Comment: @Baldrick If I refresh the page after it is loaded the link changes from "localhost:3000/about" to "/about".